# From Python to MySQL upload data failed

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

The following table is my MySQL data of field

The table named `infor`

```
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id          | bigint(7)   | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| temperature | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| wet         | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| created     | timestamp   | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

When I want to upload data to my MySQL server

I use the following code:

```
temperature_item = '8.7`c'
wet_item = '0.87%'
cur.execute("INSERT INTO infor (temperature,wet) VALUES (temperature_item,wet_item)")
```

Then it shows the error following:

> pymysql.err.InternalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'wet_item' in 'field list'")

But when I type:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO infor (temperature,wet) VALUES ('87`c','8.7%')")
```

It could work, and I have searched the previous question

Did I add the unprintable word? Or another problem?

Comment: did you try my answer?

Comment: thx it worked !!!

Answer (score 1):

```
"INSERT INTO infor (temperature,wet) VALUES (temperature_item,wet_item)"
```

This is a python [string literal](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html). Your `cur.execute` statement is exactly equivalent to typing in the following at the mysql console.

```
INSERT INTO infor (temperature,wet) VALUES (temperature_item,wet_item)
```

Now do you have a wet_item defined in mysql? No so the above error is the result.

This is also a string literal

```
"INSERT INTO infor (temperature,wet) VALUES ('87c','8.7%')"
```

But here you are passing constants to mysql which it can deal with quite easily. If you wanted to pass your variable through to mysql the correct form is

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO infor (temperature,wet) VALUES(%s, %s)", (temperature_item,wet_item))
```

Comment: thank you!!! this is very useful^^ but why after execute the sql statement ,the sql server didn't catch any data?

Comment: sorry I didn't understand that comment

Comment: Execute `cur.commit()` after your last query.

Comment: @RobinKoch op hasn't said he is using transactions so I kept it simple

Answer (score 0):

I don't know python very well, but https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-select.html, it seems you should pass your parameter when you execute it.

So if you try this :

```
query = ("INSERT INTO infor (temperature,wet) VALUES (%s,%s)")
temperature_item = '8.7`c'
wet_item = '0.87%'

cursor.execute(query, (temperature_item, wet_item))
```

Comment: thank you!!! this is very useful^^ but i don't know after execute the sql statement ,the sql server didn't catch any data?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-transaction.html , did you commit ?

Answer (score 0):

Python has no variable expansion in strings. So in

```py
cur.execute("INSERT INTO infor (temperature,wet) VALUES (temperature_item,wet_item)")
```

Python does *not* replace the variable names with it's values. (How is python even supposed to know when you want that?)

The general solution in python is the `.format()` method:

```py
s = "World"
print("Hello {}".format(s))
```

which replaces the curly braces with the *value* of `s`.

However in this particular instance (working with databases) the better solution is

```py
cur.execute("INSERT INTO infor (temperature,wet) VALUES(%s, %s)", (temperature_item,wet_item))
```

it's the way of the DB-interface to insert variables values.
It's the better way, because it also makes sure this does not happen:

```py
temperature_item = "87c"
wet_item = "8.7%'); DROP TABLE infor; --"
cur.execute("INSERT INTO infor (temperature,wet) VALUES('{}', '{}')".format(temperature_item, wet_item))
```

which would be bad.